# RestEasy - ResteasyServletInitializer fail

Tags: java, tomcat, resteasy

So....

I've been able to config a RestEasy service and **make it work in my Eclipse on Windows 8** but it doesn't work when I deploy it on a Tomcat 7 installed on a Ubuntu !

When I start my tomcat on Eclipse, I got the message :

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
>  nov. 12,
>   2014 4:00:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>  nov. 12,
>   2014 4:00:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MessageBrokerServlet'
>   **[INFO ] 2014-11-12 16:00:08,001 org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment - Deploying  javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class fr.mycompany.myproject.MarkersApplication**

but this last line isn't present in the log of the tomcat server on the ubuntu
=> thus when I calling my Rest service (via javascript /jsapi), I got this message :

```
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet RESTEasy JSAPI a généré une exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.jsapi.JSAPIWriter.generateEtag(JSAPIWriter.java:111)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.jsapi.JSAPIWriter.writeJavaScript(JSAPIWriter.java:36)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.jsapi.JSAPIServlet.service(JSAPIServlet.java:73)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and what is null (I suppose) is the `serviceRegistries` of the generateEtag() method, which is populate with my RestService when launch in Eclipse Tomcat.

I haven't a clue about why the ResteasyServletInitializer get launch/init, so if anyone got this situation (and the solution ^^), please help me T_T

Here is the configuration I use :

The application declaration :

```
@ApplicationPath("/resteasy")
public class MarkersApplication extends Application {

}
```

The service :

```
@Path("/markersRest")
public class MarkersRest {

    @Context
    private ServletContext  context;

    private DataService getService() {
        return WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context).getBean(DataService.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getMarkers(@QueryParam("keyCache") String keyCache) {
        String markers = getService().getCachedMarkers(keyCache);

        return Response.ok().entity(markers).build();
    }

}
```

The web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>MyProject</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ************************ -->
    <!-- ******* LISTENERS ****** -->
    <!-- ************************ -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- ************************ -->
    <!-- ******* SERVLETS ******* -->
    <!-- ************************ -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/spring/spring-flex-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RESTEasy JSAPI</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.jsapi.JSAPIServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RESTEasy JSAPI</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest-js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

the pom.xml :

```
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jsapi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

and the file `/WEB-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`
with the content `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.servlet.ResteasyServletInitializer`

Comment: "and the file /WEB-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer with the content org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.servlet.ResteasyServletInitializer" -- as far as I can tell, it doesn't look like this part does anything at all..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've found \o/, and for those how meet this problem here is the solution :

add the servlet declaration in your web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>fr.mycompany.myproject.MarkersApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

AND override the methods on your SubApplication :

```
@ApplicationPath("/resteasy")
public class MarkersApplication extends Application {

    private static final Set<Object>    singletons  = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MarkersApplication() {
        singletons.add(new MarkersRest());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. :) Very helpfully.

Comment: My ResteasyServletInitializer isn't doing anything either... I'm unclear what exactly you were missing in the question that made it work? Just the web.xml entries?

Comment: @Amalgovinus: sorry, I haven't work with RestEasy since (more Spring rest), so I don't remember this problem :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a catch 22 when using the Javascript API Client generator. This is caused by the fact that Wildfly/JBoss only loads a JAXRS application on demand.

The JSAPIServlet must be configured to generate the client Javascript code. The client then includes this javascript script in the page. The browser then tries to fetch the client javascript which activates the JSAPI servlet. The JSAPI servlet then scans for any loaded JAXRS applications and finds none (because they are only loaded on demand). The JSAPI Servlet then returns error html code instead of the required javascript. The client code tries to use the Javascript API to make a call to the JAXRS application and cannot because the required client script is invalid.

So the client cannot make a call to the JAXRS endpoint becuase it does not have the script and the JSAPIServlet will only generate the script if the JAXRS endpoint is loaded, hence the catch 22.

An obvious solution would be to to use a @ApplicationPath annotation parameter to force a load-on-start similar to that on a @WebServlet(load-on-start=1), however this does not appear to be possible!

There are three possible solutions that I know of to bypass this problem:

1. Solution 1

After *deployment* immediately make a call to a JAXRS endpoint to force the loading of the application. This must be done before the client javascript is loaded. This is a bad idea for so many reasons.

2. Solution 2

Do this all manually in the web.xml. Using the following web.xml to force the JAXRS application to load on startup:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mydomain.api.MyJAXRSApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, things get more complicated now because when starting the application manually, it does not itself scan for any @Path annotated endpoints and these have to all be loaded manually in the MyApplication class as follows:

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class MyJAXRSApplication extends Application {

    private static final Set<Object>    singletons  = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MyJAXRSApplication() {
        // See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892417/resteasy-resteasyservletinitializer-fail
        singletons.add(new RestServiceA());     // Each annotaed with @Path()
        singletons.add(new RestServiceB());
        singletons.add(new RestServiceC());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

3. Solution 3

To use annotations and the endpoint annotation scanner - useful if you want to be able to easily add new @Paths to the app. Here we extend the two servlets to force load-on-start:

start the JSAPIServlet using an annotation:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/rest-js", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class JSAPIServletStartupHack extends JSAPIServlet {
}
```

and to start the JAXRS application on start:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class HttpServletDispatcherHStartupHack extends HttpServletDispatcher {
}
```

I don't know if this approach has any downsides or side-effects but it appears to work for me.